# How to return largest value in an array masm assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a question from a class asking to find the largest element in an assembly array and returning it using the eax register. Most of the solutions I find are using two letter registers which seem to be 16 bit registers that don't include eax. Here is what I have wrote so far with barely a clue what I am doing.

```
.data
Array dword 10,34,2,56,67,-1,9,45,0,11
.code
_main proc near
    mov eax, @data
    mov ds, eax
    mov esi, offset Array
    mov ecx, 10
    mov bl, [esi]
    
    loopA:
    cmp [esi], bl
    jg large
    compare:
    inc esi
    loop loopA
    
    large:
    mov bl, [esi]
    jmp compare
leave
retn
```

What is the proper way of figuring out how to find the largest element in an array using 32 bit registers?

Comment: `bl` is not even 16 bit, it's 8 bit. If you want to use `eax`, just use it instead :) That is in fact a 32 bit register and would be correct for processing a dword array.  You should also do `add esi, 4` and not `inc esi`. Note, if you are running this in windows you must not set `ds`. It is already set up for you. Furthermore `esi` is a callee saved register, you must preserve its value.

Comment: Since you want 32-bit code, you could write in C and get MSVC to make some example asm for you.  (Compile with `-O1` or `-O2`). https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Okay and how would I stop the loop @Jester

Comment: `loop loopA` stops it all right, except you fall through into `large`. Move the last two instructions up to before `large:`.